# Waiting children processes

Tags: c, process, ipc

Whenever I read about children processes in C spawned by fork(), the parent waits for the children to finish. However, I am facing another problem:
I want to spawn two children, then make them wait until the parent gives them work to do.

f.example:
In client:

`fork() two children`

```
in parent, connect to a server
server returns some work to do
parents hands work over to children
```

How can I achieve this?
I am not asking for a large chunk of code, just some guidance and perhaps some code to explain.

Comment: A pipe in the parent can talk to child via pipe(2)

Comment: They need a way to communicate wi the parent. This is called Inter-Process Communication  (IPC). On UNIX, for a directly forked chuld, this is usually a pipe.

Comment: Make the child read a message from a good old pipe or a message queue, and that'll put it to sleep until a message becomes available.

Comment: Small example of what previous commenters have suggested: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

Comment: Thank you guys! Could you perhaps make an answer, such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Inter-Process Communication (IPC) between a parent and a child process. This is extremely common.

If you want to communicate to a child process you need to use a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). Unix/C utilizes pipes via [pipe(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).